# Pre-aggregated datastructure in clojure

Tags: clojure, olap, aggregation

In OLAP-cubes it's possible to do very quick look ups on large amounts of aggregated data. The major reason for this is that one pre-aggregates data in operations which are easy to combine upwards (mainly +, -, mean, std, max, min and some more).

How to get this "anti-lazy" behaviour in clojure?

I'm thinking on something like

```
(def world-population {:africa 4e8            ;;this is an aggregation!
                       :africa/liberia 3.4e6
                       :africa/ethiopia 7.4e7
                       ...})
```

How to update a datastructure like this and make sure the parents of an entity is updated too? Do one have to roll one's own ref-implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a recursive rollup function as a higher order function, something like:

```
(defn rollup 
  ([data heirarchy func]
    (loop [top (second (first heirarchy))]
      (if (nil? (heirarchy top))
        (rollup data heirarchy func top)
        (recur (heirarchy top)))))
  ([data heirarchy func root]
    (let [children (reduce (fn [l [k v]] (if (= v root) (cons k l) l)) '() heirarchy)
          data (reduce (fn [d c] (if (d c) d (rollup d heirarchy func c))) data children)
          child-values (map data children)]
      (assoc data root (apply func child-values)))))
```

Which can then be used with any particular rollup operation or hierarchy you like:

```
(def populations { :africa/liberia 3.4e6
                   :africa/ethiopia 7.4e7})

(def geography {:africa/liberia :africa 
                :africa/ethiopia :africa
                :africa :world})

(rollup populations geography +)
=> {:africa           7.74E7, 
    :world            7.74E7, 
    :africa/ethiopia  7.4E7, 
    :africa/liberia   3400000.0}
```

Obviously it gets more complicated if you have very large data sets or multiple hierarchies etc., but this should be enough for many simple cases.

Comment: This is awesome! Clever way of using higher-order functions! The geography will probably be a good match for derive, will try more with that one.

Answer (score 4):

By storing your data in an atom, you can add watches - essentially callbacks when the atom is updated

Something like this:

```lisp
(def world-population (atom {:africa 4e8
                             :africa/liberia 3.4e6
                             ...}))

(add-watch word-population :population-change-key
      (fn [key ref old new]
         (prn "population change")))
```

You could build some event propagation logic on top of that.

Comment: add-watch is a clever way to keep the structure in sync! Thank you for that one!